# How do I automatically migrate the host's SSH public key to my Puppet-based Vagrant Virtual Machine

Tags: ssh, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

Is there a way to migrate my Host's public ssh key to my VM?
The use case is:

I have a user who has a public SSH key which has access to a certain repository.
I am creating a VM that will be distributed to other developers (who have access with their SSH keys to this repository)
I would like to automate git cloning of the repository so it happens during exec-once ..
What should I do that involves as few manual paths as possible?

PS: I am using https://puphpet.com/ to generate the vagrant machine for me - I am not editing the Vagrantfile direclty.

Comment: I am assuming there is something unusual occurring here that prevents you from a simple file transfer and then git clone with either the shell or puppet provisioner. What would that be?

Comment: yep a simple [vagrant file provision](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) - make sure the right of file is correct after it gets copied to `~/.ssh` but that should be ok

Comment: you mean the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file? I am creating my VM with https://puphpet.com/ so I am not editing the Vagrantfile direclty.

Comment: Please add the Vagrantfile snippet

Comment: edit your `puphpet/config.yaml` file and set `forward_agent:true` in the `ssh` section

Comment: Thank you @FrédéricHenri . I wish puppet would include this in their documentation somewhere. You can add your comment as an answer so I Can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you can use a [vagrant file provision](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) to copy your private key on your VM

in your Vagrantfile add

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ... other configuration

  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", destination: "/home/vagrant/id_rsa.pub"
end
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried it multiple times but with no success.

Comment: precision: it actually forwards the private key and not the public one

Comment: actually I am not even sure if it does what I want. The desription says `If true, agent forwarding over SSH connections is enabled. Defaults to false.`

Comment: sorry I mixed up the question with another, as mentioned in earlier comments use file provision to push your files from host to VM